# Lotus Notes - Add a Form Programmatically - NotesForm

Tags: c#, com, lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-domino

I would like to copy a form from one NSF to another NSF programmatically. I am aware that the NotesDocument class has the CopyToDatabase method, and the NotesDatabase class has the CreateView method.

However, I have not found anything to allow me to add a form to an NSF.

I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.2, COM, and C#.

I have no problem retrieving information about forms or deleting them, and I have the following code snippet:

```
        //NotesConnectionDatabase and nd2 are objects of type NotesDatabase and are 
        //members of the same session.

        //Write the name of each form to the console.
        //Delete each form from the database.
        for (int i = 0; i <= (((object[])NotesConnectionDatabase.Forms)).Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((NotesForm)((object[])NotesConnectionDatabase.Forms)[i]).Name);
            ((NotesForm)((object[])NotesConnectionDatabase.Forms)[i]).Remove();
        }

        //For each form in nd2, copy the form to NotesConnectionDatabase.
        for (int j = 0; j <= (((object[])nd2.Forms)).Length - 1; j++)
        {
            //I am aware that there is no such method as NotesForm.CopyToDatabase
            ((NotesForm)((object[])nd2.Forms)[j]).CopyToDatabase(NotesConnectionDatabase);              
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `NotesNoteCollection` class you can get a collection of the forms. The `SelectForms` property should be set to `TRUE` and the rest should be set to `FALSE`.

After building the `NotesNoteCollection` it will contain a collection of form (documents) that can be accessed like this:

```
nid = nc.GetFirstNoteId
  For i = 1 To nc.Count
    Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(nid)
    nid = nc.GetNextNoteId(nid)id
  Next
```

The document can be copied with the `CopyToDatabase` method

Answer (score 0):

For the C# users...

```
        //NotesConnectionDatabase is of type NotesDatabase.

        //A NotesNoteCollection represents a collection of Domino design 
        //and data elements in a database.
        NotesNoteCollection nnc;
        nnc = NotesConnectionDatabase.CreateNoteCollection(false);
        //All the different types of elements default to false.
        //Set SelectForms = true to add forms to the collection.
        nnc.SelectForms = true;
        nnc.BuildCollection();

        //...

        string nid = nnc.GetFirstNoteId();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nnc.Count; i++)
        {
              NotesDocument doc = NotesConnectionDatabase.GetDocumentByID(nid);
              doc.CopyToDatabase(ndDestination);
              Console.WriteLine(nid + " copied");
              swCopyForms.WriteLine(nid + " copied");
              nid = nnc.GetNextNoteId(nid);
        }
```